# Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, xml

I've found an error on a page in my Magento application; it always show this message error when I visit it:

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/.../lib/Zend/Feed/Abstract.php on line 95

Can you give me a solution? I'm using magento 1.4.1.1.

Comment: This answer (enable php-xml) seems coherent, why doubt it instead of just testing it? From a few google searches it seems to be one of the possible issues

Comment: i just scare when i try "yum install php-xml", it will disturb my magento site..

Comment: `DomDocument` instead of `DOMDocument` can sometimes fix this issue .

Answer (score 458, accepted):

You need to install the [DOM](https://www.php.net/en/dom) extension. You can do so on Debian / Ubuntu using:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php-dom
```

And on Centos / Fedora / Red Hat:

```
yum install php-xml
```

If you get conflicts between PHP packages, you could try to see if the specific PHP version package exists instead: e.g. `php53-xml` if your system runs PHP5.3.

Comment: For Cent OS: http://smartwebdeveloper.com/centos/install-the-php-dom-extension-on-centos

Comment: installing php-xml solved this for me but don't forget the 'service httpd restart'

Comment: I was running php 5.5 with the webtatic repo (Cent OS) and had to do `yum install php55w-xml` and that worked fine for me. Of course have to restart afterwards.

Comment: @ws_123 specify your php version while installing like `php70w-xml`

Comment: i have same problem and run  yum install php-xml so have error No Match for argument: php-xml

Comment: @zzapper thanks, that got me on the rails! In my case I needed to restart apache2 `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: remember to restart apache afterwards

Comment: Worked for me running `php5.6` on ubuntu 14.04 and using the `dompdf` package.

Comment: on CentOS, module `php-xml` can be (at least for v5.6) installed with `yum install php56w-common`; see https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/
another (possible) pitfall may be, that only the file `/etc/php.d/xml.ini` but not `/etc/php-cli.d/xml.ini` is present.

Comment: For PHP7, it's just `php-doc`.

Comment: For me: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml`

Comment: For Ubuntu, `apt install php-xml` does the trick. And, of course, restarting apache afterwards `systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: i'm not able to run this command in my namecheap hosting terminal. 
how can i resolve that error?
Thank You

Answer (score 247):

**PHP 8.2**

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php8.2-xml`
- CentOS 8 [with `php:remi-8.2` enabled]: `dnf install php-xml`

**PHP 8.1**

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php8.1-xml`
- CentOS 8 [with `php:remi-8.1` enabled]: `dnf install php-xml`

**PHP 8.0**

- Ubuntu: `apt-get install php8.0-xml`
- CentOS 8 [with `php:remi-8.0` enabled]: `dnf install php-xml`

Comment: remember to restart apache afterwards

Comment: I'm running PHP 7 (7.0.15-1~dotdeb+8.1) on an Nginx VS (via Docker) and this worked like a charm!   Don't forget to do `docker-compose restart'!

Comment: PHP 7.2, CentOS `yum install php72w-xml` and then restart service

Comment: Is there not a `php-xml` alias/virtual package?

Comment: This is also starting to occur with php7.3 to 7.4 transition. When the web server PHP module is based on 7.3 and php-xml is 7.4. Updating to a consistent PHP version (either one) works fine.

Comment: In addition to restarting Apache, remember if you are using php's built in web server to kill and re serve your application.

Comment: 2022 Update: This is what I needed, `sudo apt-get install php8.1-xml`, thanks!

Comment: It required me to sudo on php8.2 and Apache restart (Linux mint 21)

Answer (score 33):

**PHP8**: (latest version)

```bash
sudo apt-get install php8.0-xml
```

**PHP7**:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

You can also do:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php-dom
```

and `apt-get` will show you where it is.

Answer (score 10):

```
Package php-dom is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.1-xml 7.1.3+-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  php7.0-xml 7.0.17-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  php5.6-xml 5.6.30-9+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

In case anyone using 5.6 versions then go with this way

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

For PHP ver PHP7, Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

or by

```
yum install php-xml
```

Answer (score 8):

After a long time suffering from it in PHPunit...

For those using namespace, which is very common with Frameworks or CMS, a good check in addition to seeing if php-xml is installed and active, is to remember to declare the DOMDocument after the namespace:

```
namespace YourNameSpace\YourNameSpace;

use DOMDocument; //<--- here, check this!
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm using **Centos** and the followings worked for me, I run this command

```bash
yum --enablerepo remi install php-xml
```

And restarted the Apache with this command

```bash
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks, restarting the server worked!  I had to do `service apache2 restart` on ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Create an empty PHP file and put only `<?php phpinfo();` in it, look at it in a browser.
Check if you can spot `--disable-dom` in the configuration options and/or if you can see details about the DOM extension in the list below.

If you cannot see DOM in the list or you see it is disabled, your PHP installation does not include the DOM extension. You'll need to recompile your PHP installation from source to remedy that.

Comment: i found --disable-dom in Configure Command, what should i do next?

Comment: That depends on your system. Worst case you have to recompile PHP from scratch.

Comment: Relying on configure option is most often a mistake, read http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2010/09/29/phpinfo-BUG-or-PEBKAC so it have been removed from phpinfo output in some distrobution (debian, fedora...)

Comment: If compiled from source, you could use `--enable-dom`

Answer (score 4):

For PHP 7.4 Install the DOM extension.

**Debian / Ubuntu:**

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Centos / Fedora / Red Hat:**

```bash
yum update
yum install php74w-xml
systemctl restart httpd
```

For previous PHP releases, replace with your version.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was it was the use of namespace at the top of php file, exemple :

```php
namespace MediaWiki\Extensions\ParserFunctions;
```

To solve this problem add the following line:

```php
use DOMDocument;
```

So no need of installing dom or xml if they are already installed. It is a php language trap.

Answer (score 3):

This help for me (Ubuntu Linux) PHP 5.6.3

> sudo apt-get install php5.6-dom

Thats work for me.

Answer (score 3):

On a Amazon Linux 2 with PHP 8.0, I had to

```bash
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php80
yum install php-xml
```

Do not forget to restart PHP

```bash
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Suse Linux (Linux linux 3.16.7-48-default) and PHP 5.6.1 as root, this helped:

```
zypper in php5-dom
```

plus restart

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

On fedora 26:

```
dnf install php-dom
```

Fixes it !

Answer (score 1):

For Centos 7 and php 7.1:

```
yum install php71w-xml
apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 1):

If compiling from source with `--disable-all` then DOMDocument support can be enabled with
`--enable-dom`

Example:

```bash
./configure --disable-all --enable-dom
```

Tested and working for Centos7 and PHP7

Answer (score 1):

I'm using CentOS 7 with virtualmin and three PHP versions. I also have REMI repo enabled. it worked for me:

## Step 1:

Just append PHP major version number like this `php{version number}-xml`. And run `yum install`

```bash
yum install php70-php-xml
yum install php71-php-xml
yum install php72-php-xml
```

### Step 2:

Don't forget to restart Apache:

```bash
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.X Centos 7

I got dependency issues when trying to install module with above suggestions, adding this flag:

`--enablerepo=remi-php7X`

Resolved dependencies.

So

`sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php7X install php-xml`

Then

`service httpd restart`

Ref:
[Install PHP Modules](https://tecadmin.net/install-php7-on-centos7/#post-9400)

Comment: Better to keep "remi-php7x" always enabled, as explained by the wizard, https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PHP7.0 to install Magento, I suggest to install all extensions by this command

`sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-xml php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-cli php7.0-mysql php7.0-gd libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-intl php7.0-soap php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath`

I need to Google some times to meet Magento requirement.

I think you can replace the PHP version to 7.x if you use another PHP version

And restart Apache is needed to load new extensions

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score -1):

this is the lastest for php v 8.0

```bash
sudo apt-get install php8.0-xml
```

Answer (score -1):

sudo chmod -R 775 path
sudo chmod -R 777 path
sudo apt-get install php8.3-xml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).