# Magento2 backend fatal error after backup recovery

Tags: php, magento, dom, magento2

After a backup recovery on my magento2 website I get this error:

> Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'DOMDocument' not found in
>   /home/arredeom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:364\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /home/arredeom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(109):
>   Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('__construct('_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...',
>   '_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))\n#4
>   /home/arredeom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(269):
>   Magento\Framework\Config in
>   /home/arredeom/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on
>   line 364\n

I've checked on cpanel config and on PHP Selector | extensions it says: Current PHP version:  7.0 and Dom is enabled (flag is on)

is there any way to fix it? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/magento-class-domdocument-not-found

Answer (score 0):

PHP told you

> Class 'DOMDocument' not found ...

The `DomDocument` class is a [fundamental part of PHP's XML handling](http://php.net/domdocument).  If the `DomDocument` class is not present, that means whomever updated your backend server didn't [include this fundamental part of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php).  This is common in some Linux package management features that slice up core PHP functionality so users can install only what they need.

The way to fix this is to install PHP's XML/DOM functionality.  The way you do that will depend on which linux distribution you're using.

Comment: I've just checked on cpanel config and on PHP Selector | extensions it says Current PHP version:  7.0 and Dom is enabled

Comment: @LaurenFrida Then the version of PHP that cpanel is looking at and the version of PHP running your code are different

Answer (score 0):

You need php-xml :

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```