# ERROR: Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, linux, domdocument, centos7, codeception

**I am using Centos 7, PHP7.0.14**
I ran **codeception for the very first time then I got an error message saying**

**Test  tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php

[Error] Class 'DOMDocument' not found**

Saw many posts recommending  **php-xml**, which sadly didn't quite worked for me.

**Below is the Error I get!**
 
Error: Package: php-xml-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
 
  Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7
 
  Installed: php-common-7.0.14-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
 
     php-common(x86-64) = 7.0.14-1.el7.remi
 
  Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
 
      php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7

Can someone please help out on this?
**It will be great if it includes the reason with the solution!** 
Thank you! :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/class-domdocument-not-found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [dom](http://php.net/dom) extension, as you have installed PHP 7.0 from **remi-php70** repository, you need to pull this extension from the same repository.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php70 install php-dom
```

Probably simpler to enable this repository permanently to avoid such issue in the future, and take benefit of upcoming versions

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
yum install php-dom
```

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Comment: Thank you it gave me a big help! :)