# AWS EC2 Class 'DOMDocument' not found Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I have search high and low and many hours for this but I really can't find.
I have gone through installing LAMP on the Instance - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

All solutions ask me to install

```
yum install php-xml
```

which I did but still getting the same error. What dependencies am I missing? Help is much much appreciated!

I am using dompdf.
PHP version 7.2.11

Comment: try `yum install -y php-xml`

Comment: i did that @murtuzahussain

Comment: Package php-xml-7.2.11-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version. tried extension=dom.so on php.ini too

Comment: Try explanation on this link then [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/class-domdocument-not-found)

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm` after installing the module!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `-y` in the command

```
# yum list installed | grep php-xml
# yum info php-xml
Available Packages
Name        : php-xml
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.3.3  
Release     : 40.el6_6
Size        : 106 k
Repo        : updates 
Summary     : A module for PHP applications which use XML
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-xml package contains dynamic shared objects which add support
            : to PHP for manipulating XML documents using the DOM tree,
            : and performing XSL transformations on XML documents.
# yum install -y php-xml
```