# nginx PHP 7.2 Install

Tags: php, nginx, php-7.2, nginx-config

I Installed PHP 7.2 on my ubuntu server in order to upgrade my PHP. I ran these commands to update my php version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install unzip zip nginx php7.2 php7.2-mysql php7.2-fpm
```

But when I run php.info page it still shows my old version of php running.

After some research, I think I have to edit my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mySiteName`

But I am not sure what to change in this location for my new php I just installed:

```
location ~ .php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.seekadventure.net.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Comment: Seems your old PHP version is the one using `/var/run/php7-fpm.seekadventure.net.sock`. You need to change the `fastcgi_pass` to the socket file written by php7.2fpm

Comment: @Phil where do I find that path written by php7.2 fpm?

Comment: On my server (PHP 7.0), it's defined in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` ~ `listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that PHP7.2-FPM is running, if not, then start it:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm status

sudo service php7.2-fpm start  # (if the service isn't running already)
```

Then go to `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`. You should see that the PHP7.2-fpm (process manager) is listening to the socket at `listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`

Then replace `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.seekadventure.net.sock;` with  `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;`

Lastly, restart `nginx` and `PHP7.2-fpm`:

```
sudo service nginx reload

sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: That gave me an http error 500 when I tried to run my website. I feel like I am close

Comment: Open `/var/log/nginx/error.log`... What do you see?

Comment: It's looking like you have problems with your script. Run `php.info`, let's ascertain that your PHP-FPM version has changed.

Comment: Good. I will suggest you accept the answer. We can chat about your failing script in a chat room or you can create a new question so that other contributors can chip in.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/class-domdocument-not-found for your failing script.

Comment: would love to chat in a chat room, if you have time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185456/discussion-between-chukwuemeka-inya-and-searayman).